# Struts2 file upload interceptor get duplicate action errors

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2, interceptor

I am using Struts2 and EJB, when upload an file which is larger than max size, the action will get same duplicate action error, why?

```
public void validateUploadDoc() {
    if(this.hasActionErrors()) return;
  //actionerror:
  // [Request exceeded allowed size limit! Max size allowed is:
  //  10,485,760 but request was: 36,830,776!, 
  //  Request exceeded allowed size limit! Max size allowed is: 10,485,760
  //  butrequest was: 36,830,776!]
}
```

I debug the validation, find two same action errors, my other setting in file upload is ok, can anyone tell me why? I only want show one action error in JSP.

Comment: are you using struts jquery plugin?

Comment: Show you form, action configuration, validation (if any).